# Unable to sort a large file containing integers

Tags: c++, file, sorting, data-structures

My program should read a large file contains nearly 1 million integers and has to sort them any way I did it with a small test file contains nearly 100 integers and it worked but when I tried it with the large file it doesn't respond and close the window this is the problem the source code below is the  program.

```
void merge(int arr[] , int size , int low , int middle , int high)
{
int temp[size];
for (int i = low; i <= high ; ++i )
{
    temp[i] = arr[i];
}
int  i = low ;
int j = middle+1 ;
int k = low ;

while (i <= middle && j <= high)
{
    if(temp[i] <= temp [j])
    {
        arr[k] = temp[i];
        ++i;
    }
    else
    {
        arr[k] = temp[j];
        ++j;
    }
    ++k;
}

while (i <= middle)
{
    arr[k] = temp[i];
    ++k;
    ++i;
}
}

void mergeSort(int arr[] , int size , int low , int high)
{
if(low < high)
{
    int middle = (low + high) / 2;
    mergeSort(arr , size , low , middle);
    mergeSort(arr , size , middle+1 , high);
    merge(arr, size , low , middle , high );
}
}


int main()
{
vector<int> intVector;

string line_;
ifstream file_("int.txt");

while(getline(file_,line_,'\t'))
{
    int result = atoi(line_.c_str());
    intVector.push_back(result);
}

cout << endl;

int numberOfTopItems ;
cout << "plz enter how many big numbers u want " << endl;
cin >> numberOfTopItems ;


const int size = intVector.size();

int* intArray = &intVector[0];
int numberOfLines = intVector.size();
mergeSort(intArray, size, 0 , numberOfLines - 1);


int count = 0;
for (int j = numberOfLines - 1 ; count  < numberOfTopItems ; j--)
{
    cout << intArray[j] << " ";

    count ++;
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "large file"? How large? How many numbers?

Comment: If the file's too big to hold in memory all at once, you'll probably get an OutOfMemory exception. Debug to get an error message and figure out what's wrong.

Comment: Also note that [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) are not part of C++, it's an extension added to some compilers. Don't use it.

Comment: You're blowing the stack with that non-standard temporary array. Use `vector` all the way.

Comment: i still need help no answers until now

Answer (score 1):

@molbdnilo already commented on the issue, int temp[size] is allocating too much space from the stack. If you want to use an array, use malloc() and free():

```
    int *temp = malloc(size * sizeof(int));
```

or as also suggested, use a vector.

```
    std::vector<int>temp(size);
```